# Cocoa class member variable allocated inside function call nil unless forced to init/load

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I come from a C/C++ background and am currently learning a bit about Cocoa and Objective-C.

I have a weird behavior involving lazy initialization (unless I'm mistaken) and feel like I'm missing something very basic.

Setup:

- Xcode 10.1 (10B61)
- macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
- started from a scratch Cocoa project
- uses Storyboard
- add files TestMainView.m/.h
- under the View Controller in main.storyboard, set the `NSView` custom class as `TestMainView`
- tested under debug and release builds

Basically, I create an `NSTextView` inside a view controller to be able to write some text.
In TestMainView.m, I create the chain of objects programmatically as decribed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextSystemArchitecture/ArchitectureOverview.html)

There are two paths:

- first one is enabled by setting `USE_FUNCTION_CALL` to 0, it makes the entire code run inside `awakeFromNib()`.
- second path is enabled by setting `USE_FUNCTION_CALL` to 1. It makes the text container and text view to be allocated from the function call addNewPage() and returns the text container for further usage.

First code path works just as expected: I can write some text.

However second code path just doesn't work because upon return, `textContainer.textView` is nil (`textContainer` value itself is totally fine).

What's more troubling though (and this is where I suspect lazy init to be the culprit) is that if I "force" the `textContainer.textView` value while inside the function call, then everything works just fine. You can try this by setting `FORCE_VALUE_LOAD` to 1.

It doesn't have to be an `if()`, it works with `NSLog()` as well. It even works if you set a breakpoint at the return line and use the debugger to print the value ("p textContainer.textView")

So my questions are:

- is this related to lazy initialization ?
- is that a bug ? is there a workaround ?
- am I thinking about Cocoa/ObjC programming the wrong way ?

I really hope I am missing something here because I cannot be expected to randomly check variables here and there inside Cocoa classes, hoping that they would not turn `nil`. It even fails silently (no error message, nothing).

TestMainView.m

```
#import "TestMainView.h"

#define USE_FUNCTION_CALL 1
#define FORCE_VALUE_LOAD 0

@implementation TestMainView

NSTextStorage* m_mainStorage;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    m_mainStorage = [NSTextStorage new];
    NSLayoutManager* layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
#if USE_FUNCTION_CALL == 1
    NSTextContainer* textContainer = [self addNewPage:self.bounds];
#else
    NSTextContainer* textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];

    NSTextView* textView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds textContainer:textContainer];
#endif
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
    [m_mainStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];

    // textContainer.textView is nil unless forced inside function call
    [self addSubview:textContainer.textView];
}

#if USE_FUNCTION_CALL == 1
- (NSTextContainer*)addNewPage:(NSRect)containerFrame
{
    NSTextContainer* textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];

    NSTextView* textView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:containerFrame textContainer:textContainer];
    [textView setMaxSize:NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];

#if FORCE_VALUE_LOAD == 1
    // Lazy init ? textContainer.textView is nil unless we force it
    if (textContainer.textView)
    {

    }
#endif
    return textContainer;
}
#endif

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    // Drawing code here.
}

@end
```

TestMainView.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface TestMainView : NSView

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Comment: `textView` is a weak property of `NSTextContainer` and the `textView` is deallocated when it goes out of scope at the end of `addNewPage:`.

Comment: @Willeke do you know why it works if you force it?

Comment: Note that `m_mainStorage` is not an instance variable.    As for why it "works", it is likely by coincidence and probably because that call ends up triggering a retain/autorelease.

Comment: `textView` of `NSTextContainer` calls [objc_loadWeak](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418693-objc_loadweak?language=occ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with cocoa that much but I think the problem is ARC (Automatic reference counting).

```
NSTextView* textView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:containerFrame textContainer:textContainer];
```

In the .h file of NSTextContainer you can see NSTextView is a weak reference type.

[image]

So after returning from the function it gets deallocated

But if you make the textView an instance variable of TestMainView it works as expected. 
Not really sure why it also works if you force it though. ~~(Maybe compiler optimisation?)~~

It seems forcing i.e calling

```
if (textContainer.textView) {
```

is triggering retain/autorelease calls so until the next autorelease drain call, textview is still alive.(I am guessing it does not get drained until awakeFromNib function returns). The reason why it works is that you are adding the textView to the view hierarchy(a strong reference) before autorelease pool releases it.

Comment: _"Maybe compiler optimisation"_ Probably the opposite, actually, I suspect it _wouldn't_ work in a "release" build.

Comment: Now that makes a lot of sense ! However isn't the textContainer variable supposed to increase the reference counter, since the value is assigned to textContainer.textView inside initWithFrame() ? If the text container is still using it, how is it getting deallocated ?

Comment: Text container has a weak reference to text view. So the reference count does not change.

Comment: Oh ok...that's the piece of info I was missing then. Is there any workaround for this ? Like forcing the reference to be held "strongly" ? Or should I move everything back into one big function ?

Comment: Basically you need a strong reference. You can do it either having the textView as an instance variable of TestMainView  or add the textView to the view hierarchy in the addPage function.

Comment: Ooh, well spotted on the switch from `strong` to `weak`. That's a big change.

Answer (score 2):

[cekisakurek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54466227/) is correct. Objects are deallocated if there is no owning (/"strong") reference to them. Neither the text container nor the text view have owning references to each other. The container has a *weak* reference to the view, which means that it's set to `nil` automatically when the view dies. (The view has an non-nilling reference to the container, which means you will have a dangling pointer in `textView.textContainer` if the container is deallocated while the view is still alive.)

The text container is kept alive because it's returned from the method and assigned to a variable, which creates an owning reference as long as that variable is in scope. The view's only owning reference was inside the `addNewPage:` method, so it does not outlive that scope.

The "force load" has nothing to do with lazy initialization; as bbum commented, that it "works" is most likely to be accidental. I strongly suspect it wouldn't in an optimized build.

Let me assure you that you do *not* need to go around poking properties willy-nilly in Cocoa programming. But you do need to consider ownership relations between your objects. In this case, something else needs to own both container and view. That can be your class here, via an ivar/property, or another object that's appropriate given the NSText{Whatever} API (which is not familiar to me).

Comment: Thanks for details. I feel kinda cheated by the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextSystemArchitecture/ArchitectureOverview.html) now since it explicitely states
"You create all four text objects explicitly and connect them together, maintaining a reference only to the NSTextStorage object. "